# Howto customize z-labels in pm3d plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have pm3d plots using

```
set pm3d at b
```

In these plots a colored bar shows the mapping of colors to numbers. I use a transformation for the z-axis to map a functions values onto an apropriate range of z-values

```
trafo(x,y)=...
splot trafo(func(x,y))
```

Obviously the color map will now show the mapping of colors to trafo(func(x,y)), but I would like it to show the mapping of colors to func(x,y) similar to a logarithmic plot which does not show the logarithm but the argument of the logarithm at the tics on the axis. 
I know

```
set format cb "%.01t*10^{%T}"
```

but this is not exactly what I want.
The straight forward

```
unset ztics
set ztics add ("Pi" trafo(pi))
```

does not seem to work either ...

So, how can I customize the color map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The straight forward

```
unset ztics
set ztics add ("Pi" trafo(pi))
```

does not seem to work either ..."

That's because the tics on the colorbar are controlled by `cbtics`, not `ztics`.

Try:

```
unset cbtics
set cbtics add ("Pi" trafo(pi))
```

And it should work alright.

Note that if you are viewing this plot in 3-d space, the `set ztics add (...)` should show up on the z-axis.  However, if you've done `set view map` or `set pm3d map` or anything like that, it won't show up since that takes away the z-axis.